# Convert date from dd-mm-yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I need to convert the date format from `dd-mm-yyyy` to `mm/dd/yyyy`. I tried below one, but it is converting the format to `mm-dd-yyyy`.

```
packDate = packDateControl.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

I need it to be like this `mm/dd/yyyy`. How to do this in `c#`.

Thanks

Comment: Some magic? `ToString` works as usual. Double check your result.

Comment: If `packDate` is a string which it looks like it should be. I dont understand where the problem is

Comment: @user1 packDate is string

Comment: In that case there is nothing wrong with the code you have given and I think you need to reword your question

Comment: how are you outputting it? There could be something unexpected happening in your display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When used in a custom date format string, the `/` character substitutes the locale specific date separator, so for English locales, this tends to be `/`, but for Turkey, it would be `.`

So, there are a number of options, you could either quote them as text, so something like:

```
packDate = packDateControl.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy");
```

Or you could specify the locale to use:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
packDate = packDateControl.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", culture);
```

Or you could use a [standard format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx), with the relevant locale:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
packDate = packDateControl.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("d", culture);
```

For more [information on custom date format strings, check out MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what control you are using, but try . . .

```
packDate = packDateControl.SelectedDate.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Swapping .Value for .Date.

Comment: `/` is the [format specifier for date separator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator), which *might not* output as `/` (In Arabic (Algeria), it would be a `-`); This is not down to an issue with the value itself being formatted.